# Unable to obtain HttpExchange object

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

In order to write a simple web service based on an application (not in a servlet), I obtain a *NullPointerException* at the last row in the following code.

```
@Resource WebServiceContext wsContext;

// ...

MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
// HttpExchange exchange = (HttpExchange) mc.get("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.http.exchange");    // solution 1
HttpExchange exchange = (HttpExchange) mc.get("com.sun.xml.ws.http.exchange");    // solution 2
InetSocketAddress remote = exchange.getRemoteAddress();
```

I've tried both solution 1 and 2, with the same result. In both cases, the *exchange* object is null.

How can I obtain the exchange object? I'm using jax-ws on JDK 1.6.

Comment: I suggest you attach a debugger and check what keys are inside `mc`.

Comment: Keys:

`
javax.xml.ws.wsdl.port
javax.xml.ws.soap.http.soapaction.uri
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.OneWayOperation
javax.xml.ws.http.request.pathinfo
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.packet.outbound.transport.headers
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.handle
javax.xml.ws.reference.parameters
javax.xml.ws.wsdl.service
javax.xml.ws.http.request.headers
javax.xml.ws.http.response.code
`
(part 1/2)

Comment: javax.xml.ws.http.request.querystring
javax.xml.ws.wsdl.interface
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.handler.config
javax.xml.ws.http.response.headers
javax.xml.ws.service.endpoint.address
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.HeaderList
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ContentNegotiation
javax.xml.ws.http.request.method
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.packet.inbound.transport.headers

(part 2/2)